# I keep Getting a IndexError that is affecting my webscraping script

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi there I keep getting this index error on my code when I am webscraping and I am not sure how to quite solve it so any help with this would be very helpful. I will put a code sample in this and the error and where on the code the error is saying is affecting the code.

The highlighted sections are where the error is occurring and I will now put the error message is showing and these below are the bits of code that are appearing to have affected my script any help will be very much appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   results = getPageResults(postcode, page)

   

 in getPageResults
    address1.append(a.select("div.govuk-body")[0].text)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint

name = []
address1 = []
address2 = []


def getPageResults(postcode, page):
    url = 'https://www.ukrlp.co.uk/ukrlp/ukrlp_provider.page_pls_searchProviders'
    url += '?pv_pc=' + postcode
    url += '&pn_pc_d=5'  # set up distance here: 0, 1, 5 or 10 miles
    url += '&pn_pageNo=' + str(page)
    url += '&pv_layout=SEARCH'

    page = urlopen(url)
    html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    results = False

    for a in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "govuk-grid-row"}):
        result = a.select("h2")
        if len(result) > 0:
            name.append(a.select("h2")[0].text)

        address1.append(a.select("div.govuk-body")[0].text)
        address2.append(a.select("div.govuk-body")[0].text)
        results = True

    return results







print("__________________________")

postcodes = [  # "BB0", "BB1", "BB10", "BB11", "BB12", "BB18", "BB2", "BB3", "BB4", "BB5", "BB6", "BB7",
    # "BB8", "BB9", "BB94", "BD23", "BL0", "BL6","BL7", "BL8", "BL9", "BN1", "BN10", "BN2", "BN20", "BN21", "BN22", "BN23", "BN24", "BN25", "BN26", "BN27"
    # "BN3",
    # "BN4", "BN41", "BN42", "BN45", "BN50", "BN51", "BN52", "BN6", "BN7", "BN8", "BN88", "BN9", "BR1", "BR3"
    # "DE1", "DE11", "DE12", "DE13", "DE14", "DE15", "DE2", "DE21", "DE22", "DE23", "DE24",
    # "DE3", "DE4", "DE45", "DE5", "DE55", "DE56",
    # "DE6", "DE65", "DE7", "DE72", "DE73", "DE74", "DE75", "DE99", "DN10", "DN11","DN21", "DN22", "DN9"
    # "FY0", "FY1", "FY2", "FY3", "FY4", "FY5", "FY6", "FY7", "FY8"
    # "HA0", "HA1",
    #"HA3", "HA7", #"HA8", "HA9", "HU1", "HU11", "HU12", "HU13", "HU2", "HU3", "HU4", "HU5", "HU6", "HU7", "HU8", "HU9",
    "L31", #"L33", "L37", "L39", "L40", "LA1", "LA2", "LA3", "LA4", "LA5", "LA6", "LA7", "LE12", "LE14", "LE6", "LE65", "LN1", "LN6"
    # "N10", "N11", "N13", "N15", "N17", "N18", "N2", "N22", "N4", "N6", "N8", "N81", "NG1", "NG10", "NG11", "NG12", "NG13", "NG14", "NG15",
    # "NG16", "NG17", "NG18", "NG19", "NG2", "NG20", "NG21", "NG22", "NG23", "NG24", "NG25", "NG3", "NG4", "NG5", "NG6", "NG7", "NG70", "NG8",
    # "NG80", "NG9", "NG90", "NW10", "NW2", "NW26", "NW6", "NW8", "NW9", "OL12", "OL13", "OL14", "PR0", "PR1", "PR11", "PR2", "PR25", "PR26",
    # "PR3", "PR4", "PR5", "PR6", "PR7", "PR8", "PR9", "RH15", "RH16", "RH17", "RH18", "RH19",
    # "S1", "S11", "S12", "S17", "S18", "S19", "S21", "S26", "S30", "S31", "S32", "S33", "S40", "S41", "S42", "S43", "S44", "S45", "S49", "S8",
    # "S80", "S81", "SE10", "SE12", "SE13", "SE14", "SE15", "SE16", "SE23", "SE26", "SE3", "SE4", "SE6", "SE8", "SE9", "SK12", "SK13", "SK14",
    # "SK17", "SK22", "SK23", "ST14", "TN18", "TN19", "TN2", "TN20", "TN21", "TN22", "TN3", "TN31", "TN32", "TN33", "TN34", "TN35", "TN36",
    # "TN37", "TN38", "TN39", "TN40", "TN5", "TN6", "TN7", "TN8", "UB6", "W10", "W9", "WA11", "WN5", "WN6", "WN8"
]

for postcode in postcodes:
    print(postcode)

    page = 1

    while True:
        results = getPageResults(postcode, page)
        sleep(randint(1, 3))

        if results == False:
            break
        page += 1
        print(page)



serve = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": name,
    "address1": address1,
    "address2": address2
})


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["name", "address1", "address2"])

df = df.append(serve)  

df.to_excel("Five_miles_9.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: *a.select("div.govuk-body")* is returning an empty list. You'll need to figure out why that might be happening

Answer (score 1):

When the are no elements in a page you are not breaking out of it the loop
and that why you are getting Index error when there are no elements `a.select("div.govuk-body")[0]` here since `result = a.select("h2")` returns empty array

```
for a in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "govuk-grid-row"}):
        result = a.select("h2")
        if len(result) > 0:
            #Only Append when length >0
            name.append(result[0].text)
            address1.append(a.select("div.govuk-body")[0].text)
            address2.append(a.select("div.govuk-body")[0].text)
            results = True
        else:
             #Since no more results breaking out
            results = False
            break
    return results
```

Also in below i have updated logic to break out

```
 for postcode in postcodes:
    print(postcode)

    page = 1
    while True:
        print(page)
        results = getPageResults(postcode, page)
        sleep(randint(1, 3))
        page += 1

        if not results:
            break
```

Try this Updated code your excel should be generated

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint

name = []
address1 = []
address2 = []


def getPageResults(postcode, page):
    url = 'https://www.ukrlp.co.uk/ukrlp/ukrlp_provider.page_pls_searchProviders'
    url += '?pv_pc=' + postcode
    url += '&pn_pc_d=5'  # set up distance here: 0, 1, 5 or 10 miles
    url += '&pn_pageNo=' + str(page)
    url += '&pv_layout=SEARCH'

    page = urlopen(url)
    html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    results = False

    for a in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "govuk-grid-row"}):
        result = a.select("h2")
        if len(result) > 0:
            name.append(result[0].text)
            address1.append(a.select("div.govuk-body")[0].text)
            address2.append(a.select("div.govuk-body")[0].text)
            results = True
        else:
            results = False
            break
    return results


print("__________________________")

postcodes = [  # "BB0", "BB1", "BB10", "BB11", "BB12", "BB18", "BB2", "BB3", "BB4", "BB5", "BB6", "BB7",
    # "BB8", "BB9", "BB94", "BD23", "BL0", "BL6","BL7", "BL8", "BL9", "BN1", "BN10", "BN2", "BN20", "BN21", "BN22", "BN23", "BN24", "BN25", "BN26", "BN27"
    # "BN3",
    # "BN4", "BN41", "BN42", "BN45", "BN50", "BN51", "BN52", "BN6", "BN7", "BN8", "BN88", "BN9", "BR1", "BR3"
    # "DE1", "DE11", "DE12", "DE13", "DE14", "DE15", "DE2", "DE21", "DE22", "DE23", "DE24",
    # "DE3", "DE4", "DE45", "DE5", "DE55", "DE56",
    # "DE6", "DE65", "DE7", "DE72", "DE73", "DE74", "DE75", "DE99", "DN10", "DN11","DN21", "DN22", "DN9"
    # "FY0", "FY1", "FY2", "FY3", "FY4", "FY5", "FY6", "FY7", "FY8"
    # "HA0", "HA1",
    # "HA3", "HA7", #"HA8", "HA9", "HU1", "HU11", "HU12", "HU13", "HU2", "HU3", "HU4", "HU5", "HU6", "HU7", "HU8", "HU9",
    "L31",
    # "L33", "L37", "L39", "L40", "LA1", "LA2", "LA3", "LA4", "LA5", "LA6", "LA7", "LE12", "LE14", "LE6", "LE65", "LN1", "LN6"
    # "N10", "N11", "N13", "N15", "N17", "N18", "N2", "N22", "N4", "N6", "N8", "N81", "NG1", "NG10", "NG11", "NG12", "NG13", "NG14", "NG15",
    # "NG16", "NG17", "NG18", "NG19", "NG2", "NG20", "NG21", "NG22", "NG23", "NG24", "NG25", "NG3", "NG4", "NG5", "NG6", "NG7", "NG70", "NG8",
    # "NG80", "NG9", "NG90", "NW10", "NW2", "NW26", "NW6", "NW8", "NW9", "OL12", "OL13", "OL14", "PR0", "PR1", "PR11", "PR2", "PR25", "PR26",
    # "PR3", "PR4", "PR5", "PR6", "PR7", "PR8", "PR9", "RH15", "RH16", "RH17", "RH18", "RH19",
    # "S1", "S11", "S12", "S17", "S18", "S19", "S21", "S26", "S30", "S31", "S32", "S33", "S40", "S41", "S42", "S43", "S44", "S45", "S49", "S8",
    # "S80", "S81", "SE10", "SE12", "SE13", "SE14", "SE15", "SE16", "SE23", "SE26", "SE3", "SE4", "SE6", "SE8", "SE9", "SK12", "SK13", "SK14",
    # "SK17", "SK22", "SK23", "ST14", "TN18", "TN19", "TN2", "TN20", "TN21", "TN22", "TN3", "TN31", "TN32", "TN33", "TN34", "TN35", "TN36",
    # "TN37", "TN38", "TN39", "TN40", "TN5", "TN6", "TN7", "TN8", "UB6", "W10", "W9", "WA11", "WN5", "WN6", "WN8"
]

for postcode in postcodes:
    print(postcode)

    page = 1
    while True:
        print(page)
        results = getPageResults(postcode, page)
        sleep(randint(1, 3))
        page += 1

        if not results:
            break

serve = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": name,
    "address1": address1,
    "address2": address2
})

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["name", "address1", "address2"])

df = pd.concat([df, serve])

df.to_excel("Five_miles_9.xlsx", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that within the website that you have as `url`, there is no `govuk-body` under `govuk-grid-row`. `govuk-body` is in a different `div` that is also a child of `govuk-width-container`. Perhaps what you meant to scrape is `govuk-body-1`. Since it can't find anything, `a` is returning an empty list, as @DarkKnight is saying in the comment above.

To make this easier to debug in the future, make sure that a doesn't have a length of zero before assigning it. You can do this by adding the following: `assert len(a.select("div.govuk-body")) != 0`. It will fail the assertion before trying to assign anything, telling you the problem with `a` before trying to execute the next step.